# Dynamically Add Images to GIF using Java

Tags: java, animation, dynamic, gif

I want to create a dynamic GIF, which I can open through browser and at the same time change by adding more frames to it programmatically and the frame immediately reflects on the browser.

Technically this means not closing the GIF image file and adding more frames and the browser keeps taking the new frame and showing it.

But what am observing is that when am adding frames, the GIF size on the disk is not changing and remains 0 bytes until the file handle is closed.

Is it that I have to keep flushing the GIF file so that the bytes value increase even before closing the file handle?

Comment: even if you are able to add frames directly browser won't load the newer version automatically. You will have to refresh the tab.

Comment: Boss,

this is already possible. Check GIF animated timers. Or gifsocket

What am asking is already done by people. So am 200% sure about it

All am asking is now how is it done :-)

When a browser opens a GIF, it doesn't know how many frames are there. And if the file handle of GIF is not closed, the browser keeps reading new frames added to GIF.